# How to decode token symbol from ethplorer.io to readable string?

Tags: tokens

I'm using [Ethplorer API](https://github.com/EverexIO/Ethplorer/wiki/Ethplorer-API) to retrieve token symbol for particular address. For this purpose I use [Get token info](https://github.com/EverexIO/Ethplorer/wiki/Ethplorer-API#get-token-info):

```
/getTokenInfo/{address}
```

In most cases I receive readable symbol but for some tokens I get unreadable ones. So the following [token address](https://api.ethplorer.io/getTokenInfo/0x5005149adcc611c47676dafdbd7d62756b4432e0?apiKey=freekey) I get the following symbol:

```
"symbol":"\ud83c\udfcb\ufe0f"
```

How can I decode to readable string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this method to convert unicode format to string.

```
function unicodeToChar(text) {
   return text.replace(/\\u[\dA-F]{4}/gi, 
          function (match) {
               return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(match.replace(/\\u/g, ''), 16));
          });
}
```

for more details

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267329/converting-unicode-character-to-string-format/22021709